# jquery select radio button using both the display style and the checked status

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

Below, the javascript function testit2() will show whether or not there is a selection for each of the four groups of radio buttons in the div1 div when you click the Test button. But if the display style for one of the groups is "none" then it fails because I can't make a selection from that group. How do I add that the buttons must be visible (i.e., the display style is inline or the visibility style is visible).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testit2()
{
    var radioscomplete = true;
    $('input:radio', $('#div1')).each
    (
        function()
        {
            name = $(this).attr('name');
            if(! $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length)
            {
                alert('Oops, you missed some input there.. [' + name + ']');
                radioscomplete = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
    if (radioscomplete)
        alert("All checked");
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<input type="radio" name="xyz">test1<br />
<input type="radio" name="xyz">test4<br />
<input type="radio" name="xyz1">1test1<br />
<input type="radio" name="xyz1">1test4<br />
<input type="radio" name="xyz2">2test1<br />
<input type="radio" name="xyz2">2test4<br />
<span style="display:inline;"><input type="radio" name="xyz3">3test4<br /></span>

<br>
<button onclick="testit2();">Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
$('input:radio:visible')
```

?

or use

```
.filter(':visible:checked')
```

Comment: (How DO you pronounce that?) Your first suggestion worked, with a caveat. To test your solution, I changed display:inline to display:none on the xyz3 control, and it worked. Thank you! (I can't upvote because I don't have the reputation!) But if I make it visible:hidden instead of display:none it DOESN'T work. Also, if I make it     `if(! $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked:visible').length)`    which is what I think your second suggestion would be, and keep the display (instead of visible) style, it ALSO DOES NOT WORK. But you gave me a solution and I am very grateful.

Comment: Oops two errors in my comment. First, I meant the style that DIDN'T work was visibility, NOT visible. Also, I meant `visible:checked` not `checked:visible` but I assume it doesn't make any difference. At any rate, neither way worked. How come the first suggestion worked and the second one didn't? Also, is there a jquery way to match on visibility

Comment: I am pretty sure you first need to get the visible before you can check their status